# Helmfile Fetch - Not able to download multiple charts from artifactory but works for a single chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

Using 'Helmfile Fetch' command to download the charts/releases mentioned in the helmfile so that I can use those downloaded charts for my further setup.
Command

```
helmfile fetch -f helmfile.yaml --output-dir samplefolder/
```

it works fine if only 1 release is mentioned in the `helmfile.yaml` file but if multiple releases then it is failing with below error :

```
ERROR:
    signal: killed
```

The under the table command is also valid but not sure why failing for multiple releases.

```
exec: helm fetch repo/chart_name --version 1.4 --untar --untardir samplefolder/   (please note this is not the actual full path but just a sample)
```

I tried the above commands but it seems its throwing 'killed' error.

Ideally this command should download the charts in the folder like how it works for a single release helmfile.